# Proof of Divergence for a Sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Previous related [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545669/negating-the-definition-of-a-convergent-sequence-to-find-the-definition-of-a-div).

After I negated the definition of a convergent sequence, I ended up with the following mathematical statement:

$$\exists\ \epsilon > 0,\ \forall\ N \in \mathbb R\ \exists\ \mathbb N \ni n > N : |x_n - l| \ge \epsilon$$

Is this correct? I'd like clarification...

Anyway, I'm now asked to use my negation of the definition of convergence to prove that $(a_n)=((-1)^nn)$ is divergent...

Am I right in assuming it's enough to prove that there exists at least one $\varepsilon$ such that $|(-1)^nn -\mathscr l|\ge\varepsilon$? Can I set $\mathscr l$ to be any real number I please?

Comment: "Is this correct?" Hardly. And this does not correspond to what is written on the other page.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

- Convergence to $\ell$ (your previous question):
  $$
  \forall\varepsilon\gt0,\ \exists N\in\mathbb N,\ \forall n\in\mathbb N,\ n\geqslant N\implies |x_n-\ell|\leqslant\varepsilon$$
- Convergence:
  $$
  \exists\ell\in\mathbb R,\ \forall\varepsilon\gt0,\ \exists N\in\mathbb N,\ \forall n\in\mathbb N,\ n\geqslant N\implies |x_n-\ell|\leqslant\varepsilon$$
- If convergence then:
  $$\exists N\in\mathbb N,\ \forall n\in\mathbb N,\ \forall k\in\mathbb N,\ n\geqslant N, k\geqslant N\implies |x_n-x_k|\leqslant1$$
- If convergence then:
  $$\exists M\in\mathbb R,\ \forall n\in\mathbb N,\ |x_n|\leqslant M$$

Can you prove that these hold and use one of these to show that $a_n=(-1)^nn$ defines a divergent sequence $(a_n)$?