# what is the general way of showing a sequence diverges and how would you manipulate this method so it works for series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

How could we show the divergence of a sequence solely by using the definition of divergence ? Also how can this general method be manipulated to work for series too?

Comment: What definition of *divergence* do you mean? Usually it is defined as *not convergent*, so you would work with the negation of that definition. See [Negating the Definition of a Convergent Sequence to Find the Definition of a Divergent Sequence](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/545669/159845)

Comment: For example the definition of divergence to infinity, i.e. S_n tends to infinity if for all H >0 there exists n>n_o : S_n >H

Comment: Alright; in that case: I answered with an example.

Comment: What do you mean with the 'manipulating it for series'-part?

Answer (score 0):

Based on OP's comment, here is a simple example to prove the sequence with terms $a_n = n^2$ tends to infinity by using the definition; we write:
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n^2= +\infty$$
if the following is satisfied:
$$ \forall H > 0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}: \color{blue}{n > N} \implies \color{red}{n^2 > H}$$
For an arbitrary $H>0$, pick $N$ so that $N > \sqrt{H}$; you then have that whenever $\color{blue}{n > N}$:
$$a_n = \color{red}{n^2} > N^2 \color{red}{>} \sqrt{H}^2=\color{red}{H}$$
so $\color{red}{n^2 > H}$.

---

How do you arrive at a good choice for $N$? You usually work backwards. You want $n^2 > H$ to hold for any $H$ and you're looking for a condition on $n$ to make this work. Since $n^2 > H \Leftrightarrow n > \sqrt{H}$ if $H$ is positive, a good choice for $N$ is anything above $\sqrt{H}$.