# Negation in the definition of convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

I know a similar question has been posted at [Negating the Definition of a Convergent Sequence to Find the Definition of a Divergent Sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/545669/negating-the-definition-of-a-convergent-sequence-to-find-the-definition-of-a-div). But there is one thing I don't really understand, or I should say there is one thing I don't really agree with in one of the solutions to this post.

Let's state the definition of convergence of a sequence first: 
"$\forall\varepsilon>0$ $\exists N\in\Bbb R$ $\forall n\in\Bbb R, n > N $such that $|x_n -\mathscr l|<\varepsilon$
$\forall n \in \Bbb N$.

Well I think the negation of the above statement should be: $$\exists\ \epsilon > 0,\ \forall\ N \in \mathbb N\ \exists\ \mathbb N \ni n \leq N : |x_n - l| \ge \epsilon$$

But it seems like everyone in that post agree that:

$$
\exists\ \epsilon > 0,\ \forall\ N \in \mathbb N\ \exists\ \mathbb N \ni n > N : |x_n - l| \ge \epsilon
$$

is the correct negation.

Is there somewhere I made a mistake? In my symbolic logic course my professor taught us both the quantifiers and also the statement attached to that quantifiers should be negated together.

I feel confused...

Answer (score 1):

The negation of 'for all $n >N$  $P_n$ is true ' is 'there exists $n >N$ such that  $P_n$ is false'. It is not 'there exists $n \leq N$ such that  $P_n$ is false'.

Comment: You are saying $\forall n, n \gt N$ is true is implying $\exists n, not(n \gt N)$ is true, but isn't this essentially $\exists n, n \le N$ is true?

Comment: No, you are not supposed to to change $n>N$ to $n \leq N$. @Metaozis

Comment: Why is so? I know quantifiers are used to indicate the range, or set, that the element will come from, isn't $\forall n, n \gt N$ just equivalent to $\forall n \in \Bbb R, n \gt N$ ? Since $n \gt N$ is essentially the statement that will determine whether is true of false?

Answer (score 0):

Your definition has
$\exists\ \epsilon > 0,\ \forall\ N \in \mathbb N\ \exists\ \mathbb N \ni n \leq N : |x_n - l| \ge \epsilon
$.

The mistake is in 
your use of
$n \leq N
$
and
$\forall\ N \in \mathbb N\ 
$.

Your definition says that
if any initial segment 
of the $x_i$ differ from
$l$ by $\epsilon$,
then the series diverges.
This would imply that
almost all sequences,
especially monotonic ones,
diverge.

What is needed for divergence is that,
for some $\epsilon > 0$,
no matter how far out you go,
there is an element that
differs from $l$
by at least $\epsilon$.